# Disable buck regulator output on startup and hold enable pin high for 1.5-2ms

Tags: dc-dc-converter, driver, buck, laser

I have a learning opportunity that I need some help with :)

I have current regulator design I put together using the LED2001 IC for driving laser diodes. This is mounted on top of a heatsink module which is mounted to an open frame CNC machine.

Here are the Kicad source files.
[Kicad Source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5570668/Laser%20Drivers/PWM_CC_LaserDriver.zip)

Here is an image of it on my machine.
[image]

The issue that I'm having is that when power is first applied to the board, the dim/enable pin needs to be held high for a brief period before the output of the LED2001 will operate on pulse widths of 1-99% (0% being 0vdc & 100% being 5vdc).

If I don't apply this technique when I first power it on, the output will not turn on until I go above 25% on the pulse width. When cutting stuff this is not a problem as the power is usually set to 100% for the cut opperation but when I'm engraving an image and the start of the engraving happens to be in a light area of the image it will not turn on the laser until it reaches a dark part of the image.

At first I thought it might be an issue with my design but I have since found references to similar designs that seem to indicate that this has something to do with the LED2001 IC.

A suggestion was made to me to disable the output while holding the dim pin high for a brief period at start up (to let the caps charge) and then bring the dim pin low and then enable the output, allowing the PWM signal to control the output after that.

I could slap a mcu on the board to do this but I thought that this would be a good opportunity to learn how to accomplish this without using a micro. I have been searching google for ideas but I don't think I'm using the right key words.

If this is trivial and you want to post a schematic, that is fine. I'll take it and try to learn how it works. OR, if you don't mind pointing me in the right direction or helping me learn the parts that would make this work, I can certainly do the research.

Thanks
John

Edit: Here are some screenshots from my O'scope.

1. 16% PWM after applying power to the board.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs93p.png

2. 97.3% PWM, not quite fully on yet..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5fqn.png

3. 97.7% PWM, the driver is on and full PWM range is available.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhGkI.png

4. back to 16% PWM.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV1Kc.png

Edit: since LTSpice didn't have a NOR gates built in, I found an example using some inexpensive BC817 BJTs. Here is what I came up with that seems to work ok based on the feedback provided in the comments.

I ended up with two NOR gates and one NOT gate which seems to do what I need it to do. When the device is powered on, it should hold the DIM pin high for about 1.5ms and then return back to 0V and stay there until the PWM signal is present, at which time it will control the DIM pin.

The output of the first NOR gate is also used to offset the feedback pin voltage at startup which should limit the output current and basically shutting off the output without adding a mosfet as a switch inline with the output.

Here are some screenshots from LTSpice.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9JQs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7kD8.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxG5p.png

Comment: Define time for " held high for a brief period"  THis can easily be done in software or hardware with an RC controlled one shot gate.. without burning out Laser from excess pulse width but   sufficient to start at low PWM without hysteresis.   1us? 1ms?

Comment: Thanks, I'll google up on RC controlled one shot gates. The pulse time needed is about 1.5 to 2ms.

Comment: Do you need to switch the output off while this is happening as well?

Comment: Yes the output needs to be switched off so the laser does not come on. :)

Comment: I took a look at the datasheet. Section 5.3 Soft-start explains the issue. During the initial DIM-high period, one possible way to trick the device not to run may be to raise the FB pin voltage. That can be accomplished by couple of summing resistors and a transistor to inject some current. That way you do not need to insert an extra device (e.g. MOSFET) into the power path.

Comment: I guess I misread it then. Thanks for the tidbit about the feedback pin idea. That sounds like a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is an example the inverts your PWM twice and gives a 600us one shot to EN

Comment: That's definitely a move in the right direction. Let me add a little more detail on how it is used.

Comment: The machine gets turned on and then the user sits down at his/her computer and connects to the machine through a USB virtual com port. When the user is ready to start the engraving/cutting process, they will click a button that starts streaming the GCODE to the machine. The PWM signal will only be sent to the laser when it is in the process of engraving. Since the PWM signal turns the laser on and off, any delays will be seen in the engraving. This is why I was thinking it needed to happen at start up so that when the engraving process starts, there is no impact to the work.

Comment: So in a nutshell, this special power on start up cycle needs to happen well in advance of any PWM signal being seen on the dim pin.

Thanks for the example. I have some homework to do now :)

Comment: The circuit above will do what you asked for using 2 NOR gates ( 1 NOR gate as a inverter)  You dont need the switch or pulldown R.. THat is just your virtual software switch. Just increase C for the ms required.  I wonder if you have actually measured this characteristic on a scope and understand why it is needed.

Comment: So something like this?
[link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc2g02.pdf)

I'll play with this in ltspice tonight and see if I can figure it out :)

Comment: yes any CMOS NOR gate will do, what you asked for, assuming what you asked for is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Between the one shot gate and applying a voltage to the FB pin, I think this will work great. I'm modeling it up in LTSpice now.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment about seeing this behavior on the scope. Here are some images from my scope that should help explain what is going on.

Comment: add photos to question pls.

Comment: I just tried but it says I can't add more than 2 links :(

Comment: Here are the links to the images since I can't seem to post them in the question.

1. 16% PWM after applying power to the board.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs93p.png

2. 97.3% PWM, not quite fully on yet..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5fqn.png

3. 97.7% PWM, the driver is on and full PWM range is available.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhGkI.png

4. back to 16% PWM.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV1Kc.png

Comment: links without the prefix can be added ... so this is  DIM in, & I out?  I don't yet understand the cause/effect of what 1 ms DIM in will do internally, but see the storage time constant effects here. Perhaps there are two soft starts. Power up and 1st drive out for some reason, I'm not getting it.. I suspect it is a high side boost cap somewhere .. nope./. maybe loop phase lead compensation

Comment: Yes, the images are DIM in and I out. 

According to the datasheet, this is what it says about the soft start.

"The startup phase is implemented ramping the reference of the embedded error amplifier in
1 ms typ. time. It minimizes the inrush current and decreases the stress of the power
components at power-up.
During normal operation a new soft-start cycle takes place in case of:
• thermal shutdown event;
• UVLO event.
The soft-start is disabled when DIM input goes high in order to maximize the dimming
performance."

Comment: It's last sentence. if DIM=hi , soft start disable and maximize dimming performance seems contradictory, and how does this prevent hysteresis you see below 30% on starting PWM. why are soft start and hysteresis linked when you say this occurs well after power up. There is no thermal or UVLO event.

Comment: yet the datasheet does not show any hysteresis effect just a normal 2nd order settling response with zero current overshoot (only undershoot)

Comment: if you need the 1ms pulse on the beginning of PWM, I can do this too

Comment: Yes, that line about disabling soft start is what confused me too. I added some screenshots of what I came up with in LTSpice using some inexpensive BJTs. This should only add about 20 cents to the BOM.

When the device is powered on there is no PWM signal and the DIM pin is pulled down with a 10K resistor (currently). 12V is applied to the board and the only thing running is the fan for the laser. When the engraving/cutting starts, is when the PWM signal is present. This can be seconds to minutes after power has been turned on. So, the startup circuit can't impact the PWM signal after.

Comment: looks good,  I hope all power up sequences are ok

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure and test for that. I figure I can change the RC component values if I need to hold it high longer. For instance, in case the startup current for the fan causes any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you could also solve it in software only. Just have the very first command always send a very very short 30% intensity signal either off on the side or on the location of the first engraving place.

Comment: For my personal use I have a macro setup in one of the software packages I use with the laser that does that for me. Its ok for testing and my personal use but I'll need to resolve this before final release since I won't have control over what software people use and IMO it just needs to work for them.

Thanks

Comment: @iceman1979
 is it the 1st pulse that needs to be stretched or power EN pulse can have some idle between 1shot EN and  PWM?

Comment: Typically there shouldn't be a PWM signal when the device is powered on so the default state of that pin would be low due to the 10K pull down resistor. I need to provide an initial "manufactured" pulse to the enable pin on power up for a short time and then release it to its default state and allow normal PWM to control the enable pin.

Comment: I did some googling for one shot gates and found an article on a non-retriggerable one shot circuit. This might do what I need. Then for the output, I'm thinking I could reverse the output of the one shot and use that to keep the output disabled with a mosfet that can handle the 4A current requirements of this design.
Thoughts?